# async WCF method WebOperationContext is null after await

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

In the following example, the method is exposed as a WCF service operation and the service is hosted in IIS.
On entry into the function the WebOperationContext.Current is set as expected.  After the await has finished waiting, however, the WebOperationContext.Current is set to null.

```
        public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        //WebOperationContext.Current is set

        Task t = new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(10000));

        t.Start();

        await t;

        //WebOperationContext.Current is null
    }
```

This would seem to be a shortcoming, so I wondered if anyone was aware of this and if there were any good ways around it.  I realise I could cache a reference to the conext in a local variable, but this doesn't seem great.

Update

One approach that works is

```
            public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;

        Task t = new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(10000));

        t.Start();

        await t;

        //ctx is set        
    }
```

and also, as others have hinted at, I could do this

```
        public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("WebOperationContext.Current", WebOperationContext.Current);

        Task t = new Task(()=>Thread.Sleep(10000));

        t.Start();

        await t;

        WebOperationContext ctx = (WebOperationContext)CallContext.LogicalGetData("WebOperationContext.Current");
    }
```

What would be the implications in terms of performance and thread safety of each?

Answer (score 5):

I've heard the WCF team is considering solutions for `OperationContext.Current`, and I expect they will address `WebOperationContext.Current` as well. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797091/operationcontext-current-is-null-after-first-await-when-using-async-await-in-wcf) (note that Jon Cole is on the MS WCF team).

In the meantime, you can capture the value in a variable (which improves testability, and is what I recommend), add it to `LogicalCallContext`, or install your own `SynchronizationContext` (which would be tricky since you're hosted in IIS which uses its own `SynchronizationContext`).

Comment: I had seen that post, but hadn't realised JC was on the team, hence I thought I'd ask again.  It would seem like a good candidate for fixing, though am not sure what trickery would be involved, given await implies the following code block will execute on a different thread.

Comment: The complexity comes in because WCF is host-neutral. `await` will capture and resume on a "context", but this is usually `SynchronizationContext`, which is determined by the host and not WCF (and has no "hooks" for inserting your own data to flow with the context, other than `LogicalCallContext`, which would have a fairly significant performance hit if the WCF team just used it all the time and also may flow over remote calls and into other appdomains). So I don't know *how* they're going to solve it. ;)

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you thought the best way to capture the value in a variable would be, is it safe just to store a local reference and use this or should I do more?

Comment: It's safe to use a local (or instance) variable; I would expect that to be faster than `LogicalCallContext`. But I would consider a refactoring that would remove `WebOperationContext` from `TestAsync` completely - IoC, possibly using DI. That way your `TestAsync` is easily testable.