# Accessing WCF OperationContext asynchronously

Tags: .net, wcf

Recently I have read the following [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797091/operationcontext-current-is-null-after-first-await-when-using-async-await-in-wcf)

According to the colleagues from this thread, it is safe to reference OperationContext.Current  from another thread just by capturing the reference (with or without help of OperationContextScope).

My question is: is this really true? I can see many disposable members of OperationContext. According to a very simple test - reference captured OpertionContext from thread pool queued thread - values like IncomingMessageHeaders go away (are disposed and no longer valid).

Isn't more safe to grab from request thread what's required and don't rely on the lifetime of operation context and its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, from [Msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx):

> Use the OperationContext from within a service operation to access the
>   **current operation execution environment**. In particular, the operation
>   context is used to access callback channels in duplex services, to
>   store extra state data across portions of the operations, and to
>   access incoming message headers and properties as well as add outgoing
>   message headers and properties.

and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733816.aspx)

> OperationContext – This class represents the operation information
>   that the runtime gathers for each operation. This includes information
>   such as the incoming message headers, the incoming message properties,
>   the incoming security identity, and other information. **Extensions of
>   this class can either extend the behavior of OperationContext or store
>   the state for each operation.**

I think you can get some service configurations, that allow you access to OperationContext values (playing with instance management of the service, service mode, ...). But - in this case, if your' service instance mode will be changed in the future - you can break all the functionality, built with this assumption.

I agree with you and prefer to take care of state values (when and if required) by myself.