# HttpContext.Current is null after await completed in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, async-await, httpcontext

I have the following simple WCF service defined in .NET 4.5 web app:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "json/DoWork/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Task<string> DoWork();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public async Task<string> DoWork()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current != null);
        var s = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");
        Debug.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current != null);
        return s;
    }
}
```

And the web.config is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"
                 targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebApplication1.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="WebApplication1.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                           httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The output is

```
True
False
```

Shouldn't the context be available after await completed in .NET 4.5?

Comment: not sure, that question is about OperationContext not HttpContext

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520290/using-the-aspnetsynchronizationcontext-from-wcf-hosted-in-iis) perhaps.

Comment: @AndreiN.: What's the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`? `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.UseSynchronizationContext` *should* default to `true`, but you might want to try setting it explicitly anyway.

Comment: @StephenCleary I set the ServiceBehavior attribute to true but the  SynchronizationContext.Current is null

Comment: also, as a sanity check, I checked HttpRuntime.TargetFramework when running and it says 4.5

Comment: @AndreiN.: Is `SynchronizationContext.Current` null *before* the `await`?

Comment: @StephenCleary yes, it's null before await

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the service. I stumbled on this issue, because I'm seeing the same behavior.  When I execute the method HttpClient.GetStringAsync in my controller action the httpcontext.Current is gone.

When I do this with the sync version, it is still there..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?