# HttpContext.Current becomes null after the first await

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, httpcontext

I created `WCF` service with `aspnetcompatibility` and `webHttpBinding`. At the beginning of method marked with `WebGet` attribute I have `HttpContext.Current` but it becomes `null` after 1st `await`. I tried both options: with `ConfigureAwait(false)` and without. You can find test project [here on github](https://github.com/MaximTkachenko/wcf-async-httpcontext-null). How to fix it?

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfAsync
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    //[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = true)] - TRIED THIS, IT DOESN'T WORK
    public class Service1
    {
        [OperationContract, WebGet]
        public async Task<string> GetStr(bool configureAwait)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["threadid"] = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
            if (configureAwait)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null
                ? "null httpcontext"
                : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["threadid"] == null
                    ? $"new httpcontext, threadid =  {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
                    : $"original httpcontext, threadid = {System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["threadid"]}";
        }
    }
}
```

It's my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfAsync.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfAsync.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469258/httpcontext-current-is-null-after-await-completed-in-net-4-5) but there is no answer. So I create this one with example project on github.

Comment: You have been here long enough that the code needs posting here, not somewhere else.  Please post your minimal viable example here.

Comment: What happens if you hold on to the context before the await and then access it after?

Comment: @Nikosi it works this way.

Comment: @mtkachenko can you confirm your last statement. Was my suggestion an acceptable answer?

Comment: Ensure that you are targeting at least .NET 4.5 and using at least ASP.NET 4.5.

Comment: @Nikosi I khew it before posting this answer. I want to know whether it's possible to fix it properly.

Comment: @mtkachenko What is there to fix if there is a way where it works?

Comment: Are you using IIS Express or normal IIS by the way?

Comment: @Nikosi The method you described is a workaround. I want to know why it works this way and whether it's possible to force it to work properly.

Comment: @Evk I tried both.

Comment: @Evk I added web.config as well.

Comment: Well it seems that's just not supported, see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/558df0bf-4cac-47a6-9cdc-9f0d4f8dd534/alternative-to-the-operationcontext-when-using-asyncawait?forum=wcf. I assumed that if you run under asp.net 4.5 your WCF would use its synhronization context which has support for async\await, but it seems not the case. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520290/using-the-aspnetsynchronizationcontext-from-wcf-hosted-in-iis

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Bouke Since the question is still open - no, I haven't found a solution.