# Scope gets lost in Castle Windsor typed factory?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I have following Windsor component registration code in a container with TypedFactoryFacility:

```
Component
    .For<IMyItemFactory>()
    .AsFactory(f => f.SelectedWith(new MyComponentSelector()))
    .LifestylePerWcfOperation(),

Classes
    .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .BasedOn<IMyItem>()
    .LifestylePerWcfOperation()
    .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)),
```

that strives to create autoimplementation of IMyItemFactory. During execution of IMyItemFactory factory method program fails with exception

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException: Could not obtain scope for component SpecificItem. This is most likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component outside of web request etc)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.GetScope(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(String key, Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal kernel, IReleasePolicy scope)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IMyItemFactoryProxy.GetMyItem(String myItemType)
```

It's confusing as practically every component in the application has WcfOperation scope, so I don't understand how this can happen. I even try to log every registered type with its scope to assert that IMyItem classes have WcfOperation scope – and they have.

Do you have any idea how to debug this?

Edit: I am calling the factory from successfully constructed object with WcfOperation-scope that calls another WcfOperation-scoped services without a problem:

```
public SomeDataProvider(IElasticsearchClient elasticClient, IMyItemFactory factory)
{
    _elasticClient = elasticClient;

    _factory = factory;
}

async Task SomeMethod()
{
    var someString = await _elasticClient.SomeMethod(); // ok

    var myItem = _factory.GetMyItem(someString); // exception from above

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you using the factory?

Comment: I added description of the usage. I guess this question is difficult to answer from distance - I would be satisfied by an answer that would teach me how to debug this situation. As I already wrote, my only idea was to assert myself that everything is in the same scope using a `Container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers` call.

Comment: If a replace `LifestylePerWcfOperation` by `LifestyleTransient` for `IMyItemFactory` and `IMyItem`s, it resolves `IMyItem`s correctly, but I need to use some `WcfOperation`-scoped components from some of `IMyItem`s, so that's unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: is `OperationContext.Current` `null` when you're calling `_factory.GetMyItem()`?

Comment: It's null! Thank you! That's it, I think it's this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797091/operationcontext-current-is-null-after-first-await-when-using-async-await-in-wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `OperationContext.Current` was `null` so technically Windsor was doing the right thing - alerting you to the fact.